# Button going crazy when I hover on the <i> in it (using jQuery animation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this button, and I want to change width when I hover over it with some other effects, anyway when I do hover over it the button starts going crazy, it starts going the width then collapses even when I'm not mouseout-ed it. Here's the code:

```js
$("body").ready(function(){
      var w = $(".smthnbox").css("width");
  $(".smthnbox").mouseover(function(){
    $(".smthnbox").animate({
      width:"200px"
    },400);
  });

  $(".smthnbox").mouseout(function(){
    $(".smthnbox").animate({
      width: w
    },400);
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.smthnbox{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background: blue;
  margin:20px auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/34f0dfa89d.js"></script>
    <link href="smthn.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Welcome | Check it out !</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button class="smthnbox">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <script src="smthn.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the previous incomplete animation before the next one.

```
$(".smthnbox").stop().animate({...});
```

Comment: it worked thanks, but i ddnt understand, when you put stop() it finished the animation and doesnt let other animations to play? please if u can elaborate that would be great

Comment: Because animation has a duration, when you stack up jQuery animations, one needs to complete before the next is executed. stop() simply terminates the current animation execution (doesn't matter if finished or not) and leaves the element at that state, and the next animation will begin execution. In your example, because mouse event is bind to ".smthnbox", when you mouseover the <i> element the mouseout event for ".smthnbox" is fired, thus stacking up the animation. When you mouse out <i>, mouseover for ".smthnbox" is also fired.

Comment: oh okay great, thanks! one more thing is there any smoother way ? cause when i accidentally hover over the "i" element it stops, can I get "i" out of the way?

Comment: Obsidian Age answered it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.mouseout` is also triggering on the `<i>`, which is a different element to `.smthnbox`. To prevent the `.mouseout` logic from also applying to elements contained **within** `.smthnbox`, you need to pass `event` to `.mouseout`, and then check which element has the event. If it's not the target element, prevent the behaviour. This can be achieved with the following:

```
$(".smthnbox").mouseout(function(event) {
  var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
  if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
    return;
  }
  // Intended functionality
}
```

This results in the `.mouseout` only triggering when the user's mouse *truly* leaves the element:

```js
$("body").ready(function() {
  var w = $(".smthnbox").css("width");
  $(".smthnbox").mouseover(function() {
    $(".smthnbox").animate({
      width: "200px"
    }, 400);
  });

  $(".smthnbox").mouseout(function(event) {
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
      return;
    }
    $(".smthnbox").animate({
      width: w
    }, 400);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.smthnbox {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/34f0dfa89d.js"></script>
  <link href="smthn.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>Welcome | Check it out !</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="smthnbox">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <script src="smthn.js"></script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

use th mouseenter and mouseleave event listeners

```js
$(function(){
  var box = $(".smthnbox")
  var w = box.css("width");
  box.on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
      width:"200px"
    },400);
  }).on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
      width: w
    },400);
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.smthnbox{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background: blue;
  margin:20px auto;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/34f0dfa89d.js"></script>
    <link href="smthn.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Welcome | Check it out !</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button class="smthnbox">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <script src="smthn.js"></script>
    </body>
```